# UIDatePicker does not update the 'Today' flag when the date advances

Tags: iphone, date, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatepicker created in UIBuilder and instantiated once when the app first loads. When first presented, the datepicker correctly flags today's date with the word 'Today'. On IOS 4, if I dismiss the app to the background, and reactivate it a day later, the date has advanced, but yesterdays date is still flagged as 'Today'. Explicitly updating the controls date has no effect. It looks like the control determines 'Today' only once, when created.

I've tried calling init to re-initialise it in-situ, but can't get that to work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably not.  [Please file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com), and someone on the UIKit team will investigate it.

Comment: Update: Apple have acknowledged this as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIDatePicker from Interface Builder. But when you return to the app you need to execute

[datePicker sizeToFit];

and it will updates "Today" cell.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for this bug you might catch the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification and dump and recreate the table cells to get a correct 'today' flag.

Answer (score 0):

The UIDatePicker shows the default value from your Interface Builder setting. I added UIDatePicker in viewDidLoad{} but not in Interface Builder, it works well.